# How to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\max\{0,a+x\})^k f(x)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I try to understand how to integrate the maximum function when the maximum function is raised to an integer power. That is, I want to calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\max\{0,a+x\})^k f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
where I'm primarily interested in the cases $\mathrm{k=\{2,3,4\}}$.

For $\mathrm{k=1}$, I can rewrite the expression to get

$$\begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \max\{0,a+x\} f(x)\mathrm{d}x &=a+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \max\{-a,x\} f(x)\mathrm{d}x \\ &=a-a\int_{-\infty}^{-a}  f(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-a}^\infty x f(x)\mathrm{d}x,\end{align}
$$

and I know how to calculate these integrals.

But it doesn't seem to be possible to use the same trick when $\mathrm{k}$ is an integer larger than $\mathrm{1}$.

Comment: Maybe one can use the fact that $\max\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand is $0$ when $x <-a$. So the integral is $\int_{-a}^{\infty} (a+x)^{k} f(x) \, dx$ Exapnd $(a+x)^{k}$ by Binomial Theorem. You get $\sum_{j=0}^{k}  \binom {k} {j} \, a^{j}   \int_{-a}^{\infty}x^{k-j} f(x) \, dx$